# User-independent session data: is it implemented anywhere outside of Embperl?

Tags: perl, apache, session, embperl

**Preface**

- Normally, a session in a web application stores data for a specific user (and its data is available across any visit of the user to the same web server/site).
- Embperl (a templated web development framework in Perl) has a very interesting feature: user-independent session data stored/retrieved at the level of individual web page (`%mdat` hash).

**QUESTION**:

- Does a similar feature (user-independent "session" data accessible to all users' requests) exist in any other web development environments/stacks, either in precisely the same form (perl web page data) or somewhat similar?

  I am specifically asking about a feature implemented/accessible as part of a web framework, not the obvious and easily done DIY solution of "well you can easily implement your own via a $backend_database_store with a key of the page URL" .

  This is a purely theoretical question borne of my trying to find non-Embperl analogue to help explain Embperl's `%mdat` feature. I don't care which web development stack/framework the example is from, as long as it's not something totally obscure used by 3 people in the universe :)

**Background**:

This came about from trying to answer a recent Embperl question about `%mdat` hash; I tried to explain it by comparing it to some other feature in web development. I then realized that I don't actually KNOW any other framework with a similar feature. buit I'm sure on MUST exist :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although it called "cache".

e.g. in Mason $m->cache will return your whatever object. even a %mdat if you like to.

http://www.masonhq.com/docs/manual/Devel.html#data_caching

Your "user-idependet session data", smells like cache, looks like a cache and reads like cache. Only missing some features - e.g. you can use $m->cache at every level of your application.

Comment: Hmm... I'm tempted to say "how's that different from the DIY solution?". But this is kind of hazy, since `%mdat` isn't all THAT different from a cache storing a hash keyed off of the page URL... Oh well, +1 but I can't really claim this as the accepted answer since the per-page aspect is still DIY